# Android sending sms onload JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i use this script on my landing pages, but the user needs to click a button for it to work.

```
<a onclick="ClickTrack('click5')" href="smsto:NR?body=TEXT" class="btn_2" >
    <strong><span class="cta-clik">Click to send sms</span></strong>
</a>
```

Does anybody know how to make it work without button click but when website Loads?

Comment: Use $(document).ready  or $(window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the redirect part, you can make a function like this:

```
function redirect()
{
    window.location.href = "smsto:NR?body=TEXT"
}
```

If you use JQuery, you could use `document.ready` inside your script file:

```
$('document').ready(funtion(){
  redirect();
});
```

If you don't, include the script in the bottom of your page like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- content here -->

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        redirect();
    });
    </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: This is not my js code onclick="ClickTrack('click5'). this line was added by someone to track click. I jut need to run this part: href="smsto:NR?body=TEXT" class="btn_2" >
    <strong><span class="cta-clik">Click to send sms</span></strong>
</a>

Answer (score 1):

Personally I dislike the inline bindings but you could try putting it on your body tag

```
<body onload="ClickTrack('click5')">
```

If possible bind in your logic or just call it like @randy was saying.